# Authenticate to OAuth2 services-Cannot resolve method getAuthToken

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0

I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate) tutorial but i'm stuck on the **getAuthToken**.It says cannot resolve this method

Here is the code i have:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Bundle options = new Bundle();

    Account[] accounts=am.getAccountsByType("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/");


    am.getAuthToken(
            accounts,                     // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
            "Manage your tasks",            // Auth scope
            options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
            this,                           // Your activity
            new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
            new Handler(new OnError()));    // Callback called if an error occurs

}
```

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem. How did you solve it? (five years later :D )